# Loading JSON file dynamically does not work in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, java, json, javafx

I have a JavaFX application that saves data to a local file data.json which, for example, looks like
`data = '[{"name":"Jack","pet":"turtle"},{"name":"John","pet":"black mamba"}]'`. Periodically the application adds more entries to this file.

In my html file that I am loading to that application I need to show all this info. I have a script tag that loads that file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../Data/data.json" id="dataSourceScript"></script>`

Then in js code I have `var mydata = JSON.parse(data)` which allows me to load that JSON into `mydata` variable as described [here](http://www.askyb.com/javascript/load-json-file-locally-by-js-without-jquery/).

As I need to update the page content when new entries are added, I have a function I call every couple seconds with `setInterval()` that does that. In order to get the updated file info, I delete that old `<script>` tag and add a new one (exactly the same), but this means that `data` now has the updated info:

```
var oldScript = document.getElementById("dataSourceScript")
if(oldScript)
    oldScript.remove()

var newScript = document.createElement("script")
newScript.setAttribute("id", "dataSourceScript")
newScript.setAttribute("src", "../Data/data.json")
document.body.appendChild(newScript)
var mydata = JSON.parse(data)
//then I just add the new entry to DOM, if there is a new entry
```

It all works great. If I open my html file in browser and then add a new entry to the file, in a few seconds the page gets updated and shows the new entry too. However, for some reason it does not work in my JavaFX application. It loads the file just once from the initial `<script>` tag, but if I change data.json file, nothing happens. I have to close the application and reopen it in order to get the new info shown on the page.

(I didn't find any other way to read a file that would work. FileReader just stops reading when a file gets updated, which defeats the purpose; fetch() and XMLHttpRequest() both get blocked by CORS policy; I cannot create a server to request files or install Node or anything else, I need pure html+js to be the UI)

Comment: The file is being cached a one or all of t: 1) the server, 2) a proxy/gateway/loadbalaner 3) the browser. You'll need to turn off caching for that resource.

Comment: Or maybe set some kind of no-cache policy header to the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to the comments, thanks guys.

Yes, the file I loaded from script tag was being cached and not being updated. A solution is very easy, I just needed to create a variable counter and add it as a version to the new script every time I create it, so it's considered a new one

```
var version = 0
...
var oldScript = document.getElementById("dataSourceScript")
if(oldScript)
    oldScript.remove()

var newScript = document.createElement("script")
newScript.setAttribute("id", "dataSourceScript?version=" + version++)
newScript.setAttribute("src", "../Data/data.json")
document.body.appendChild(newScript)
var mydata = JSON.parse(data)
//then I just add the new entry to DOM, if there is a new entry
```